# PHP - Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12864 bytes)

Tags: php, memory-management, file-upload, fatal-error

I get this error when I try to upload a file of 3,424KB and got this error

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12864 bytes)
```

but its fine when I try to upload a file thats 4,891KB why is this?

Also I have updated my php5.ini file and the permissions are fine and everything.

Any tips would be awesome thanks!

J

this is the line of the code where the error occurs:

```
 $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
```

Comment: Include the line number from the error and associated code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gd library fully uncompresses your `.jpg` file in memory. So only the size in pixel matters, not how big the uploaded file is.

You need to increase your [`memory_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) a bit.

Answer (score 0):

### Tips

A. GD fails since images are uncompressed.

B. User `memory_limit` to increase memory

C. Use Imagick it is memory efficient

D. Re-size your image to manageable size

Example

```
try 
{
    $img = new Imagick ( $imageLarge );
    $img->thumbnailImage ( 500, 500, TRUE );
    $img->writeImage ( $imageCute );
} 
catch ( Exception $e ) 
{
    echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage (), "\n";
}
```